# How to handle multiple dropdown lists in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

One of my clients wants a set up multiple dropdown lists as a set of outbound links (yes, I cringed too, but he does have his reasons...).

There are 3 dropdowns, each one pertaining to its own group of links. When each dropdown has its SelectedIndexChanged, it then redirects based on the choice made. However, lets say I make a choice in the second dropdown. It goes to the proper link. If I then choose a link in the first dropdown, it goes to the proper link. Then if I select a link in the third dropdown, it will go to the link specified in the choice I made in the FIRST dropdown.

How can I code it so that it will always select the most recent selection?

Comment: Can you provide some example code or explain better? I don't really get what you want to do with the third dropdown.

Comment: There is nothing special about the 3rd dropdown. Each dropdown is simply a grouping of links. The first list is links to people. The 2nd links to different online databases. The 3rd is to other schools. I realize this is a horrible way to organize links and it is making me cringe just thinking about it :)

Comment: Can we see your code-behind where it is handling the dropdown selection and redirection? Sounds like you have something wrong in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but I'll risk an answer. The question is not so much about cascading dropdownlist, more then retaining  the last dropdown used and its value.

You could simply use an input hidden to store "Last_value" and "Last_DropDownID"

You could also store those in the session or a cookie. Database even.

Comment: Exactly. The dropdowns are not meant to cascade at all, each dropdown is just a group of links with a common idea, one is links to people's web sites, one is to a bunch of online databases, the other is to other schools. This looks like the general idea I am looking do, and will investigate more on how to do this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, it sounds like you should just save which dropdown was used last.

To do that, just get the id of the sender control in the SelectIndexChanged Event and store it  (e.g. in ViewState, depending on your situation):

```
protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string id = ((Control)sender).ID;
     this.ControlLastUsed = id;
}
```

In the event handler of the third dropdown you can then read out this value and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the AJAX cascading dropdownlist extender.  Check it out: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: The choices are just 3 different groupings of links, so I don't need them to cascade based on what was selected beforehand. Thanks though!